# How to make Javascript show me the current time when i ask for it in an input?

Tags: javascript, input

I want to see the current time when i enter some specific text in a input but it's not working

HTML

```
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="inputcommand"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showTime()"></input>
        </form>
            <p id="output">Output here</p>
```

Javascript

```
var command = document.getElementById("inputcommand");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var showTime = function(){
var askForTime = ["What time is it?","Show me time","Time"];
if(command.value === askForTime){
    output.innerHTML = Date();
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use for loop to iterate through an array value askForTime

```
var command = document.getElementById("inputcommand");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var showTime = function(){
var askForTime = ["What time is it?","Show me time","Time"];

for(var i=0; i<askForTime.length; i++)
if(command.value == askForTime[i]){
    output.innerHTML = Date();
}
};
```

Comment: While not wrong, all modern browsers (even IE9 and above) support `indexOf()` method of arrays, no need for a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't check an array with a string. Try this:

```
var command = document.getElementById("inputcommand"),
output = document.getElementById("output"),
showTime = function(){
    var askForTime = ["What time is it?","Show me time","Time"];
      if(askForTime.indexOf(command.value)>=0){
            output.innerHTML = new Date();
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code: the elements may not exist when the code executes (if it's above the HTML), and as other answers already mentioned, you need to check for item in the array, not the array itself.

Also, better practice is binding the click event from within the JS code, not HTML:

```js
var askForTime = ["What time is it?","Show me time","Time"];
function ApplyClick() {
    var oInput = document.getElementById('inputcommand');
    var oButton = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
    if (oInput && oButton) {
        oButton.onclick = function() {
            var value = oInput.value;
            if (askForTime.indexOf(value) >= 0)
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (new Date()).toString();
        }
    }
}
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", ApplyClick, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", ApplyClick);
else
    window.onload = ApplyClick;
```

```html
 <form>
            <input type="text" id="inputcommand" />
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p id="output">Output here</p>
```